# How can I make my string property drop down the list of system font names in Object Inspector?

Tags: delphi, properties, components

How can I make my string property drop down the list of system font names in Object Inspector ? (like `Form1.Font.Name` does)

```
  TSuperList = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FFontName: String;
  published
    property FontName:String read FFontName write FFontName;
  end;
```

Comment: Take a look at how `TFont.Name` works (via `TFontName` property editor)

Comment: Shouldn't this be as simple as making it a TFontName property instead of a string?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you ! You can post the answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @Kanitatlan That's exactly what I said :-)